# Storing const* in const vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, c++14, constants

The relevant interface code that I have to deal with consists of two functions, one that retrieves objects, and the other one where I have to submit the objects as vectors. The problem is, that the retrieval function returns `const Object*`, but the submit function expects `const vector<Object*>`.

I know this is solveable with `const_cast<Object*>`, but is there a different, cleaner way?

Here is code that demonstrates the problem:

```cpp
#include <vector>

//////////// REPRESENTATIVE INTERFACE IMPLEMENTATION, DO NOT TOUCH ///////
struct Object{};

class Interface{
    public:
    size_t getNumObjects() const {return 10;}
    const Object* getObject(size_t index) const {return nullptr;}
};
const Interface interface;

void submitObjects(const std::vector<Object*> &objects);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Task: take all objects from 'interface' and submit them to 'submitObjects'.

int main(){

    std::vector<const Object*> objects;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < interface.getNumObjects(); i++){
        const Object* object = interface.getObject(i);
        objects.push_back(object);
    }

    submitObjects(objects); // ERROR: no known conversion from 'vector<const Object *>' to 'const vector<Object *>'

    return 0;
}
```

The only way that I could come up with to solve that problem is to make `objects` a `std::vector<Object*>` and insert the objects with `objects.push_back(const_cast<Object*>(object));`, but I feel like there has to be a better solution.

Any ideas are appreciated.

---

Some more background info why this is a valid problem:
`const vector<Object*>` can only deliver `const Object*`, as seen in all of its getter overloads, like seen here: https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at

Therefore, `vector<const Object*>` is almost never used in interfaces. Therefore, the idea of combining a lot of `const Object*` in one big `const vector<Object*>` is a valid concept, but seems impossible to construct without `const_cast`.

***EDIT***: Statement above is incorrect, thanks for clarifying.
`const std::vector<Object*>` ***can*** produce non-const pointers, because my understanding of pointer constness was incorrect.

Comment: @Jarod42 I agree. I was thinking about rust, where constness automatically propagates to return values.

Comment: Create a copy of vector ? Interface seems to be not clear a little.

Comment: `std::vector<Object*> const` and `std::vector<Object const*>` are two pretty different beasts! In the latter, you can change the vector's contents (add/remove/replace), but you cannot modify the objects pointed to. In the former, the vector itself *cannot* be modified – but that *only* applies to the pointers, whereas you *could* modify the objects pointed to!

Comment: @arayq2 That was a mistake from my side. Already fixed.

Comment: `const Interface interface;` sounds like a strange instance. Especially if you're going to "_take all objects from 'interface'_".

Comment: @Aconcagua that is incorrect, `const vector<Object*>` can only give you `const Object*`, that's why nobody usually writes `vector<const Object*>`, because it's sufficient to make the entire vector const. See here: https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at

Comment: @TedLyngmo it's just a demonstration of a much more complex usecase

Comment: @Finomnis I'm very sure that `const vector<Object*>` gives you `Object* const` (i.e. a `const` pointer to a mutable object, which can be coped to a `const Object*`, i.e. mutable pointer to `const` object).

Comment: This is going to entirely depend on what `submitObjects` and whether or not the objects the the pointer `getObject` returns are actually const or not.  Do you know if `submitObjects` does any modifications?  Do you know if the objects that the pointer `getObject` points to are actually const?

Comment: @Finomnis Nope. It will return `Object* const &`, not `Object const *&`! Important difference!

Comment: @Finomnis You misunderstand the documentation/typing rules. If you have `T = Object*`, then `const T` is not `const Object*` but `Object* const`.

Comment: @Finomnis Ok, so what's the purpose of having `interface` `const` for this demonstration?

Comment: The perils of west-const-ing! I've been an east-const-er for years.

Comment: By the way: `submitObjects` accepts *by value* – intended or did you forget to place the ampersand?

Comment: @Aconcagua forgot

Comment: @Everyone ... so am I a victim of the confusing const pointer notation?

Comment: Yes, you are... All the matter gets much more obvious if you decide to *always* place const to the right of where it refers to: `Object const*` vs. `Object* const` (see @arayq2 's west/east const-ers...). Try to get used to, it's helpful (but if in some project, adopt the style given there).

Comment: @arayq2 • "west-const-ing" and "east-const-ing"?  Is that the difference between `const int*` or `const int&` (which I hate, because it is the "exception to the rule" that `const` binds to the thing to its immediate left... unless `const` is first in which case contrawise binds to the thing to its immediate right), versus `int const*` or `int const&` (which I always use)?

Comment: @Eljay Exactly – look at a compass where west and east are located (and the object referred to is in the center)...

Comment: The rule is that const binds to the left, unless there is nothing to the left, only in which case it binds to the right.  East-const-ing is therefore completely regular and consistent (think of function signatures too); west-const-ing is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You misunderstand the documentation/typing rules. If you have `T = Object*`, then `const T` is not `const Object*` but `Object* const`. This how C and C++ work.

Therefore, your assertion that "you cannot get a mutable object from `const vector<Object*>` is wrong. What you cannot do is modify the vector or the values of the elements (i.e. change the pointers). But the accessors return references to `Object* const`, so can still modify the pointed-to objects:

```
void foo(const std::vector<int*>& v)
{
    (*v[0])++; // Increments the integer pointed to by the first vector element.
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/HGIb20

This is simply due to `const` not being transitive. Here is another example:

```
struct X
{
    int* y;
};

void foo(const X& x)
{
    (*x.y)++;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/NmCwGt

---

Given this, the interface you have does not allow what you want to do. You are only handed pointers to immutable objects but are supposed to pass on pointers to mutable objects (the `submitObjects` function only promises not to modify the container, but it reserves the right to modify the objects). This is simply impossible.

`const_cast` could be a valid option *if* (and that's a very important if!) you know 100% that the objects are not *actually* declared as `const` wherever they are created. But this both defeats the point of the interface and is an extremely fragile, hacky approach that you should not even consider in this circumstance.

Answer (score 5):

Your interface returns pointer to constant object. You want to send those constant object into a function that want mutable objects.

It's not just about undefined behaviour, it's about surprises.

Imagine the one implementing the interface is keeping calculated values about the objects and is flagging dirty when calling a potentially mutating method. There would a compeling reason to indeed return pointer to constant objects. Modifying the const object would break a class invariant.

If you send that constant to `submitObjects` and your object get mutated there, then you lied in a sense: an interface send you constant objects and you mutated them. You broke the contract.

If `submitObjects` don't mutate its arguments, then there is no reason to keep the argument mutable.

---

Reguarding the confusion about const, here's an example of a const vector of pointer to mutable data:

```
// const std::vector<int*>
auto const cannot_erase_or_add = std::vector<int*>{
    new int{1},
    new int{2},
    new int{3}
};

// Error!
// cannot_erase_or_add.push_back(new int{4});

// Error!
// cannot_erase_or_add.clear();

// operator[] return int*, because it's a vector of int*
int* one = cannot_erase_or_add[0];

// totally legal, int*, no const there
*one = 2;
```

On the other hand, here's the contrary:

```
// std::vector<int const*>
auto can_erase_or_add = std::vector<int const*>{
    new int{1},
    new int{2},
    new int{3}
};

// Works
can_erase_or_add.clear();

// Works
can_erase_or_add.push_back(new int{4});

// operator[] return int const*, because it's a vector of int const*
int const* four = can_erase_or_add[0];

// Can't do that, pointer to const
// *four = 2;
```

Comment: Or, to put it plainly: What the asker wants to do is impossible.

Comment: As I just added in my answer, it is impossible to get a mutable object from ``const vector<Object*>``, therefore interfaces usually don't ever require ``vector<const*>``.

Comment: @Finomnis no. a constant vector of pointer to mutable data returns pointer to mutable data. `std::vector` won't go through pointer and templates to add const there.

Answer (score 4):

Your options are:

1. Change `submitObjects` to accept `std::vector<const Object*>`.
2. Or change `Interface::getObject` to return pointer to non-const `Object`.
3. Or use `const_cast`, as you figured out. Avoid this if you can.

If `submitObjects` modifies the pointed objects, then 3. is dangerous if the pointed objects shouldn't be modified (such as if they are actually const objects). If it is OK for the objects to be modified, then choose 2.

If `submitObjects` does not modify the pointed objects, then there should be no problem with doing the change 1.

If `submitObjects` modifies the pointed objects, and it is not OK for the objects to be modified, then you have a logical contradiction, and there is no solution other than to not pass the pointers to the function.

> it is impossible to retrieve mutable pointers from a `const vector<Object*>`?

It is only the pointers that you may not mutate. But you may mutate the pointed objects. Example:

```
struct Object{ int member; };
Object o;
const vector<Object*> objects{&o};
objects[0]->member = 42; // well-defined
```

> I was thinking about 1., but that would mean that it would no longer accept std::vector, requiring yet another overload

Or, you could use a template. In particular, this may potentially be a good use case for input iterators, or ranges.

Comment: I agree with your explanation. I have a couple of follow-up questions: Is it possible for submitObjects to modify the pointed objects, as it is impossible to retrieve mutable pointers from a ``const vector<Object*>``? And yes, I was thinking about 1., but that would mean that it would no longer accept std::vector<Object*>, requiring yet another overload...

Comment: @Finomnis _"but that would mean that it would no longer accept std::vector<Object*>, requiring yet another overload..."_: Not exactly, because you could `const_cast` from non-const to const safely.